# why logout don't show and i creat it with bootstrap auth in laravel?

Tags: php, html, laravel, bootstrap-4

[here is the nav bar but the code is :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VbpSk.png)

@else

```
                            <a id="navbarDropdown" class="nav-element" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" v-pre>
                                {{ Auth::user()->name }}
                            </a>
                            <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('logout') }}"
                                   onclick="event.preventDefault();document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
                                    {{ __('Logout') }} 
                                </a>

                                <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" class="d-none">
                                    @csrf
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    @endguest
```

i can't logout

{{ __('Logout') }} 
                                    
this div don't showed

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you could use {{ __('Logout') }} as is. You may use {{ $Logout }} instead. To indicate that it came from a function in your file.

Comment: actually this is bootstrap auth , i did not write the code myself , i did not changed it and it worked for me like that, thank you for your help !

Answer (score 0):

The code you pasted here is coming under `@guest`. So it will not show up if you are logged in. There will be a menu in your code for authenticated users add logout there